# Pytorch: Dropout Layers and Packed Sequences

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

(PyTorch 0.4.0)

How does one apply a manual dropout layer to a packed sequence (specifically in an LSTM on a GPU)? Passing the packed sequence (which comes from the lstm layer) directly does not work, as the dropout layer doesn’t know quite what to do with it and returns something not a packed sequence. Passing the data of the packed sequence seems like it should work, but results in the attribute error shown below the code sample.

```
    def __init__ (self, ....):
        super(Model1, self).__init__()
        ....
        self.drop = torch.nn.Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)

    def forward(self, inputs, lengths):
        pack1 = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(inputs, lengths, batch_first=True)
        out1, self.hidden1 = self.lstm1(pack1, (self.hidden1[0].detach(), self.hidden1[1].detach()))
        out1.data = self.drop(out1.data)
```

This results in:

```
 AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Perversely, I can make this an inplace operation (again, on the data directly, not the full packed sequence) and it technically works (i.e., it runs) on the CPU, but gives a warning on the GPU that the inplace operation is modifying a needed gradient.  This gives me no confidence that the CPU version works correctly (does it?  Is it missing a warning?  Would not be the first time that I caught PyTorch silently chugging along doing something it should flag a warning for) and in any case GPU support is vital

So:

- Are the different behaviors between CPU and GPU expected?
- What is the overall correct way to do this on a GPU?
- What is the overall correct way to do this on a CPU?

Comment: you could re-pad it with `pad_packed_sequence` which will return you the padded output of the lstm and the lengths. Then you apply dropout to the output.

Comment: @blckbird I could have sworn I tried that with bad results, but on a fresh investigation it seems to work.  Runs without errors, anyway.  Still seems too cumbersome to be the intended method.

Comment: @blckbird that works well enough that if you want to write it as an answer I will upvote it, although I may not accept immediately in the hopes of finding a less cumbersome, more natural-feeling solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pad_packed_sequence`:

```
def forward(self, inputs, lengths):
        pack1 = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(inputs, lengths, batch_first=True)
        out1, self.hidden1 = self.lstm1(pack1, (self.hidden1[0].detach(), self.hidden1[1].detach()))
        out1, _ = nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(out1, batch_first=True) 
        out1 = self.drop(out1)
```

Comment: Crucial addendum:  The dropout layer should be defined as in_place, or this does not work correctly.